# Pulling data from one column to populate another

Tags: excel

Apologies if this is a completely basic question, but I am social scientist.

I have one sheet (called Clients)

Column A is client name, Column B is case manger, Column C is the month one set of paperwork is due, Column D is when another row of paperwork is due.

I am attempting to create a sheet (or separate column) that will pull the names from Column A (and correlating Column B data) if Column C or D equals the month we are in.

Example of table:

[image]

If C1 (Annual) equals January (or correlating month) I want there to be A1 (Client) & B1 (CM) to be pulled into a new spreadsheet or column.

Thanks for all the help not just for the question but for all the other searches and answers I have gotten in the past, and apologies of this is completely obvious and I am just a dunderhead.

Comment: Couldn't you just filter your data for column C?

Comment: Otherwise you can use an If function to move the data to another column.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
=IF(OR(TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()),"mmmm")=C2,TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()),"mmmm")=D2),A2)
```